# Android Espresso : Saving number of rows in listview to variable

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I have a listview that I am testing and need to count the number of rows in the list.

How Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assert the number of element in your RecyclerListView or ListView by using a custom Matcher like this :

```
/**
 * Test if a RecyclerView contain the right amount of elements
 */
fun withListSize(size: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        var listSize = 0
        public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
            if ((view !is RecyclerView)) throw IllegalStateException("You cannot assert withListSize in none RecyclerView View")
            listSize = view.adapter.itemCount
            return listSize == size
        }

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("ListView should have $size items and currently $listSize items")
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
         var listSize = 0
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.list))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
                public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
                    if ((view !is RecyclerView)) throw IllegalStateException("You cannot assert withListSize in none RecyclerView View")
                    listSize = view.adapter.itemCount
                    return listSize !=0
                }

                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    description.appendText("ListView should not be empty")
                }
            }))

    // ADD TO the list

    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.list))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(Matchers.allOf(withListSize(listSize + 1), ViewMatchers.isDisplayed())))
```

Comment: I am adding an item to a list and asserting that the size has changed, and in doing so need the original list size.  Do you know how I can get the original list size to compare to the current list size in the matcher?

Comment: You can create a matcher witch check if the list is empty with my code and use it to get back the size by calling the adapter.itemCount and next add your element and use this matcher to assert that you have the new item